# Computing toric ideals via saturation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, groebner-basis

I have recently got interested in toric varieties and I have a question concerning their ideals.

Let $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{m \times n}$ and $\ker A = \{ u \in \mathbb{Z}^n \; | \; Au = 0 \}$.
For any $u \in \ker A$ vectors $u_+$ and $u_-$ can be defined as follows:
$$u_+ = \sum_{u_i > 0}u_ie_i \textrm{ and } u_- = -\sum_{u_i<0}u_ie_i.$$
The ideal $I_A = \langle \{ x^{u_+} - x^{u_-} \; | \; u \in \ker A \} \rangle$ is no doubt toric. The well-known way to construct $I_A$ is the following one. Let $L = \{ l^1,...,l^r \}$ be a basis for $\ker A$ and
$$
I_L = \langle \{ x^{l^i_+} - x^{l^i_-} \; | \; i = \overline{1,r} \} \rangle
$$
then
$$
I_A = I_L : (x_1 \cdots x_n)^\infty.
$$
Is it right that $I_L$ is always $I_A$-primary (except for the cases when $I_L$ is principal or $L \in \mathbb{N}^{n \times r}$ - then $I_L = I_A$), i.e. $I_A = \sqrt{I_L}$? If so is there any relatively easy proof of it? If not what is the case when this statement may fail?

In addition to that:

Are there any reasonable bounds on the size of a reduced Groebner basis of $I_A$ (for example for grevlex ordering)?

Any hint or reference would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is the link to this question on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/160378/computing-toric-ideals-via-saturation-and-groebner-bases-of-toric-ideals

Comment: Can you provide a proof that $I_A=I_L:(x_1\cdots x_n)^\infty$?